# c# RSACryptoServiceProvider with CspParameters cannot set keySize

Tags: c#, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I read that we cannot set `keySize` for `RSACryptoServiceProvider(int, cspParams)`

```csharp
CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters
{
    KeyContainerName = "KeyContainer"
};
            
var rsaRoot = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParams);
Console.WriteLine(rsaRoot.KeySize); // 1024
```

The only way to set keysize is using `RSACryptoServiceProvider(int)`, How can I Set CspParameters `KeyContainerName = "KeyContainer"` with this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved I have to use unique `KeyContainerName`

```csharp
CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters
{
    KeyContainerName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

};

var rsaRoot = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParams);
```

about readonly statement ([url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.keysize?view=net-5.0#applies-to))

> The RSACryptoServiceProvider class does not allow you to change key
> sizes using the KeySize property. Any value written to this property
> will fail to update the property without error. To change the key
> size, use one of the constructor overloads.

I think me or them is misunderstood, It cannot change the keySize after created but we can initialize the keySize